# Several login levels in Lift

Tags: scala, lift

Let's say I have two user models:

```
object Customer extends Customer with KeyedMetaMapper[Long, Customer] with MetaMegaProtoUser[Customer]
object User extends User with MetaMegaProtoUser[User]
```

Both from `MegaProtoUser`. One is for the frontend, one is for the admin login only, and they're completely different. Now I think I have to add both to the sitemap:

```
class Boot {
    def boot {
        val sitemap = List(
            Menu.i("Home") / "index",
            Menu.i("Admin") / "admin" / "index" submenus User.menus
        ) ::: Customer.menus
        LiftRules.setSiteMap(SiteMap(sitemap:_*))
    }
}
```

Seems quite simple to me, but it throws an exception:

```
net.liftweb.sitemap.SiteMapException: Location Login defined twice
    Loc(Login, <function1>, LinkText(<function1>), List(If(<function0>,<function0>), Template(<function0>))) 
and
    Loc(Login, <function1>, LinkText(<function1>), List(LocGroup(WrappedArray(public)),If(<function0>,<function0>), Template(<function0>)))
```

How could I add the second login and user edit areas for the Admin user?

Comment: About my previous comment -- yes, seems like it was wrong. Another way.. Maybe you can rename the `"Login"` thing in `User.menus` or `Customer.menus` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(From looking at proto/ProtoUser.scala) Override this:

/**
   * If you have more than 1 ProtoUser in your application, you'll need to distinguish the menu names.
   * Do so by changing the menu name suffix so that there are no name clashes
   */
  protected def menuNameSuffix: String = ""

So if you set it to "xx" then instead of Login the menu name will be Loginxx.